# Make scrollbar for canvas vertically and horizontally

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to make the canvas with scroll bar.

I have a canvas `600` x `800` and a parent div `200` x `200`

So, I want to use scroll bar x and y.

I try this script, but in vain, looks like `overflow:scroll` is ignored

How can I make scroll bar for canvas?

```
const TestCanvasPage = (props) =>{
    const ref_canvas_pic = useRef();
    useEffect(() =>{
        var chara = new Image();
        var ctx = ref_canvas_pic.current.getContext('2d');
        chara.src = "test600x800pic.png";
        console.log(chara.src);
        chara.onload = () => { 
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0,ref_canvas_pic.current.width,ref_canvas_pic.current.height);
            ctx.drawImage(chara,0,0,
                ref_canvas_pic.current.width,
                ref_canvas_pic.current.height);  
    }
    });
    return (
        <div>
        <div style={{width:"200px",height:"200px",overflow:scroll}}>
            <canvas ref={ref_canvas_pic} style={{width:"600px",height:"800px"}}></canvas>
        </div>
        </div>
    );    
}

export default TestCanvasPage;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It looks like you have a small mistake in your CSS styling. The overflow property should have a value of "scroll", but in your code, it is written as `scroll` without the quotes, which is causing the issue.**

```
const TestCanvasPage = (props) => {
    const ref_canvas_pic = useRef();

    useEffect(() => {
        var chara = new Image();
        var ctx = ref_canvas_pic.current.getContext('2d');
        chara.src = "test600x800pic.png";
        console.log(chara.src);
        chara.onload = () => { 
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ref_canvas_pic.current.width, ref_canvas_pic.current.height);
            ctx.drawImage(chara, 0, 0, ref_canvas_pic.current.width, ref_canvas_pic.current.height);  
        }
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            <div style={{ width: "200px", height: "200px", overflow: "scroll" }}>
                <canvas ref={ref_canvas_pic} style={{ width: "600px", height: "800px" }}></canvas>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default TestCanvasPage;
```

Feel free to accept this as the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: Thank you , this is just a careless mistake. I really appreciated your help.